# Nanair package not having expected results

Tags: r, missing-data, chi-squared

Recently, I've been making chi squared tests with some variables from my dataset. The problem is that some variables have missing values listed as -9 instead of NA and I tried using a few tactics to remedy this:

```
Oak %>% replace_with_na_all(condition = ~.x == -9)

oakland_analysis_final %>%
   replace_with_na_all(condition = ~.x %in% common_na_numbers)

na_strings <-c("-9")

Oak %>%
   replace_with_na_all(condition = ~.x %in% na_strings)
```

to replace -9 with NA. After using a `table()` command, I confirmed that -9 was still listed. There were no apparent errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this?

```
    Oak <- data.frame(
    id = c(1,   1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1),
    values = c(1,   1,  -9, 2,  -9, 3,  4,  4,  -9, 5))

Oak

   id values
1   1      1
2   1      1
3   1     -9
4   1      2
5   1     -9
6   1      3
7   1      4
8   1      4
9   1     -9
10  1      5

Oak[ Oak == -9 ] <- NA

Oak

   id values
1   1      1
2   1      1
3   1     NA
4   1      2
5   1     NA
6   1      3
7   1      4
8   1      4
9   1     NA
10  1      5
```